# What's the general form of the rotation matrices should be used in QR decomposition

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

> Apply two iteration of the QR method to the matrix that was given
> $$
> A=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
> 3 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 3 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 3
> \end{array}\right]
> $$

**Solution:**
$$
P_1=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta & 0 \\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right] \text { so } P_1 A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
3 \cos \theta+\sin \theta & \cos \theta+3 \sin \theta & \sin \theta \\
-3 \sin \theta+\cos \theta & -\sin \theta+3 \cos \theta & \cos \theta \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
The angle $\theta$ is chosen so that $-3 \sin \theta+\cos \theta=0$, that is, so that $\tan \theta=\frac{1}{3} .$ Hence
$$
\cos \theta=\frac{3 \sqrt{10}}{10} . \quad \sin \theta=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10}
$$
and
$$
P_1 A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{3 \sqrt{10}}{10} & \frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} & 0 \\
-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} & \frac{3 \sqrt{10}}{10} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sqrt{10} & \frac{3}{5} \sqrt{10} & \frac{1}{10} \sqrt{10} \\
0 & \frac{4}{5} \sqrt{10} & \frac{3}{10} \sqrt{10} \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]=A_2
$$
Continuing, we have
$$
s=0.36761 \quad \text { and } \quad c=0.92998
$$
So
$$
\begin{aligned}
R^{(1)} \equiv A_{3}=P_{2} A_{2} &=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.92998 & 0.36761 \\
0 & -0.36761 & 0.92998
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sqrt{10} & \frac{3}{5} \sqrt{10} & \frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} \\
0 & \frac{4 \sqrt{10}}{5} & \frac{3 \sqrt{10}}{10} \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right] \\
&=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\sqrt{10} & \frac{3}{5} \sqrt{10} & \frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} \\
0 & 2.7203 & 1.9851 \\
0 & 0 & 2.4412
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I understood how they get values for those rotation matrices but couldn't understand how to determine the form of those matrices like first $P_1=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta & 0 \\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$ and $P_2=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}\right]$. Is  there any general form (like to decompose $m\times n$ matrix) to remember?

Like what will be the form if I want to zero the $d,g$ and $h$ respectively.
$$
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: This is called QR decomposition via Givens rotations, which slightly more effective than the use of general Householder reflectors for tightly banded matrices, such as tridiagonal like here, generally matrices in Hessenberg form, or the application of bulge chasing like in the modern variants of the QR iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your response @LutzLehmann. I was confused when to use which rotation matrix. Like, does the same rotation matrix format need to use to annihilate the $d$ and $g$ element?

Comment: There are several ways to use the Gives rotations. You could start by rotating $g$ into $d$, or $g$ into $a$, or first $d$ into $a$. Then rotate the remaining element of the first column into $a$. Last, rotate the resulting number in the $h$ position into $e$.